# use client side and server side datatables simultaneously in a single script

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I am integrating datatables plugin for my listing page, where show/hide columns, pagination, # of records per page, search box, column filters are there. Right now I am using server side by using

```
"sAjaxSource": baseUrl + ajaxSource,
"bServerSide": true,
```

But only for show/hide feature I don't want to use server side,instead I want to use client side. Is it possible to use client side for this particular without changing the other features- I mean other features like pagination, # of records per page, search box, column filters would be in server side and show/hide would be in client side?
My code is :

```
"sAjaxSource": baseUrl + ajaxSource,
"bServerSide": true,
"sDom": 'T<"clear">firtlip',
"bPaginate": true,
"bProcessing": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
"iDisplayLength": 25,
"aoColumns":ao
```

where baseurl, ajaxSource are returning the proper URLs and ao is returning the proper indexes.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Show/hide feature' - what do you mean?

Comment: @LukaszKoziara in Datatables plugin, one feature is there, that is for column show/hide. I am talking about that.